# Doesn`t run http handler in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler

I want to run my httphandler, when some user get access to image file with extentions like png, jpeg, gif and other. But i get eror 404 when i try to path. I think what server try find file on a disk, but i want use alias for access to file in my handler and newer access for real phisical file path.
Example config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.jpg" type="Startup.Shop.ImageHandler, Startup.Shop" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ImageHandlerfor JPG" path="*.jpg" verb="GET" type="Startup.Shop.ImageHandler, Startup.Shop" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="ImageHandler for GIF" path="*.gif" verb="GET" type="Startup.Shop.ImageHandler, Startup.Shop" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="ImageHandler for BMP" path="*.bmp" verb="GET" type="Startup.Shop.ImageHandler, Startup.Shop" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="ImageHandler for PNG" path="*.png" verb="GET" type="Startup.Shop.ImageHandler, Startup.Shop" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
/configuration>
```

Example handler class:

```
 public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IRouteHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

And more - iis server configurated as classic mode

Answer (score 0):

If you're in classic mode, then asp.net won't get called by IIS unless IIS knows the file type that should get mapped.  In your IIS control panel, you should be able to configure the file types handled by ASP.NET.  Otherwise, it's going to assume that a file type is for a physical file, which it can't find on the file system.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add about setting up a server. In the Handler mappings have next handler named ImageHandler and settings:
request path: *.png, *.jpeg,*.jpg,*.gif
executable: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll,
All verbs and path type: unspecified